# AWS Lambda Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 255 Runtime.ExitError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lambda function was working fine and suddenly started throwing error below after update:

AWS Lambda Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 255 Runtime.ExitError

Comment: Please share the code and relevant CloudWatch log entries. Best guess: The code that you "updated" is broken.

Comment: there is no code change just an image update.. I know this is related to permission, hence posted this question to find out about code 255. Also, the function is not getting invoked as there are no logs from function.

Comment: By "image update" you mean that you're using a Lambda Container Image? Have you verified that the function is referencing a valid image?

Comment: we have terraform updating the image... where would you see the error if its invalid image? the cloud watch is just throwing this error. there is no other error/log lines. the very next line after this is the billing summary.

Comment: Seems it was image issue.. I wish there was some kind of better error which comes from container flowing to cloudwatch. @Parsifal if you post a answer I can accept that. That way it may be helpful for others since its not obvious, specially if everything is working fine in unit tests etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid image issue. If would be nice if container errors can propagate to cloudwatch!